# Webpack/React app setup failing - "React is not defined"

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using webpack to set up a React app.

When I serve my app locally using `webpack-dev-server` I get `VM1086 bundle.js:9812 Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined` in the console.

I have know idea what is going on as there aren't any other errors or information to go on, as webpack seems to compile ok.

## index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./dist/bundle.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mount"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

## webpack config

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {

  entry: [
  './src/App.js',
  ],
  output: { 
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), 
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: ['node_modules'],
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        babelrc: true,

      },
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

## app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
console.log('Hello World!');




class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return  (<div>314159263</div>);

    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('mount'))
```

Comment: is React present in your `package.json`? are have you ran `npm install`?

Comment: yes react and react-dom are in node_modules.  and i've tried placing <script> after <div..>.. it still fails

Comment: what versions of webpack and webpack-dev-server do you use?

Comment: webpack - 3.5.4 ||
webpack-dev-server --- don't know how to check version, -v.. -version just boot it up :(

Comment: @AlexBollbach npm ls webpack-dev-server

Comment: Alexander-Bollbachs-MacBook-Pro:ab-site-test alexanderbollbach$ npm ls webpack-dev-server
ab-site-test@1.0.0 /Users/alexanderbollbach/Desktop/ab-site-test
└── (empty)

Comment: @AlexBollbach I recreated your case and it works for me. Could you create a repro, so I can spot the cause

Answer (score 0):

try to define bundle.js after  `<div id="mount"></div>`  because may be your bundle compiles your code and it does not find where to render the code

```
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mount"></div>
<script src="./dist/bundle.js" ></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and also in your webpack add this

```
 query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
```